# How to filter the pods based on their age in openshift cli?

Tags: command-line-interface, openshift, devops, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

Generally we get pod details by running the command

```
oc get pods
```

I wanted to filter the pods by their age. let's say I want to view the pods that are running since an hour. How can we filter the pods?

Comment: Start by playing with ``oc get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp``. Not sure if you can also use ``--template`` with some logic in it to filter.

Comment: I tried with `--sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp` but it is throwing an error.: creationTimestamp is not found

Comment: What OpenShift version are you using? I think you need a reasonably recent version.

Answer (score -2):

the latest version 3.5 list the pod as per age